# Why does the extended Lorentz force law have a negative sign?

Tags: electromagnetism, forces, magnetic-monopoles

I read on a textbook (and Wikipedia) that, if there were magnetic charges, the theoretical corresponding Lorentz force law would be
$$
\mathbf F = q_m\left( \mathbf B - \frac1{c^2}\mathbf v \times \mathbf E\right).
$$
I understand that the $c^2$ is required in order to correct the dimensions, as well as being a natural candidate since $c^{-2} = \mu_0\epsilon_0$. However, I don't understand why the negative sign is there. Is there something I'm missing, like it being necessary to be  consistent with some other law?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of looking at it is that if you write $\mathbf F = \mathbf E + i \mathbf B$ (not to be confused with the force, or with the field tensor—unfortunate notation), then Maxwell's equations can be added pairwise to get

$$\begin{eqnarray} \nabla\cdot\mathbf F &=& 4πρ \\ \nabla\times\mathbf F &=& i\left( \frac{\partial\mathbf F}{\partial t} + 4π\mathbf J \right) \end{eqnarray}$$

and the force is $q \left( \mathrm{Re}(\mathbf F) + \mathbf v \times \mathrm{Im}(\mathbf F) \right) = \mathrm{Re}(q \left( \mathbf F - i \mathbf v \times \mathbf F \right))$. If you allow the charge to be complex, then you get Maxwell's equations with magnetic charge and the magnetic force equation with the sign flip. I don't think this qualifies as a proof that the sign must flip, but it makes it seem more natural. It matches the sign flip in $\nabla\times\mathbf E = -\frac{\partial\mathbf B}{\partial t}$, and arises for the same reason in this picture.